# jQuery append destroying original element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I have a `div` at the top of my webpage where I want to append things when a user scrolls down.

I mark the things I want to append with the class `sticky-item`.

The problem is that when they are appended to the `sticky` `div` at the top of the page, they are destroyed from their original place in the HTML and cannot be replaced when the user scrolls back up.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfrxujst/1/)

How can I append the element to the `sticky` `div`, and replace it to it's original location when I scroll back by it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone and append else it is like moving that dom element from its current place to a new place.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sticky = false;
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 && !sticky) {
            sticky = true;
            // Scroll up
            $('.sticky-item').clone().appendTo('.sticky');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50 && sticky) {
            sticky = false;
            $('.sticky').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sticky"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>This is my text</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row sticky-item">
        <h2>This is some more text (pay attention it will be missing)</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h3>and finally</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
        <p>this is more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `sticky` flag is used to avoid multiple appends

Comment: When I do that, the element is cloned a bunch of times over.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wfrxujst/2/

Clone the object and remove its class then append to div:

```
$(this).clone().removeClass("sticky-item").appendTo( ".sticky" );
$(this).hide();
```

on scroll show hidden items:

```
 $('.sticky-item').show();
```